# Create a date column in oracle with default time value

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE helpToolStatsTest (
  customer nvarchar2(25),
  data nvarchar2(7),
  myDate Date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE()
)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @AlexPoole Sorry, I overlooked the tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402):

```
CREATE TABLE helpToolStatsTest (
      customer nvarchar2(25),
      data nvarchar2(7),
      myDate Date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL 
    )
```